# Is openssl enc safe enough for securing a Bitcoin recovery phrase?

Tags: encryption, openssl, bitcoin

Is openssl enc considered secure enough to protect a bitcoin recovery passphrase?

An attacker might get the encrypted text and invest several thousand dollars in computing power trying to decrypt it.

The password is about 15 characters long

The full command is:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pbkdf2 -iter 10000000 -in crypto.txt -out crypto.txt.out -a
```

Comment: There are a number of [other questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com++password+time+to+crack) on this board that walk through the math of estimating how long it will take to crack a password, given the password length, number of rounds of hashing, budget for resources, etc.  I think if you do the same math, you'll find that it will take a long time to crack a random 15 character password, especially with 10,000,000 rounds of pbkdf2 hashing, with only a few thousand dollars of resources.

Comment: But, if you really want to push the envelope, you might want to consider using a KDF that requires more resources (such as Argon2).